# iPhone App: Photo not uploaded on first attempt

Tags: ios, facebook, upload, photo, fbconnect

I am doing a photo publish with the graph API like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:theImage, @"source", nil];
[appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" 
                                         andParams:params 
                                     andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
                                       andDelegate:appDelegate];
```

The problem I get is that the first attempt creates the new album for my app but does not actually post the photo. The album is empty. If I then make a second request the photo is successfully published. Any idea what I may be doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions that your application have related with facebook